# Lightdm: Login window on wrong monitor every time

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, gnome, multiple-monitors, lightdm

**Problem:** The login window on lightdm on my Ubuntu 18.04 distribution keeps appearing on the wrong monitor (my left-most monitor). I have three monitors, the monitor I want it to appear on is DP-4 (my middle monitor). If I login and then logout, it then appears on my third monitor (right-most monitor) for some reason, which is still incorrect.

**What I've tried:**

Option 1) Edited */etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf*:

```
[greeter]
active-monitor=1
```

Tried values of 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4. Not sure what other values I can try, didn't work.

Option 2)

Created and edited */usr/bin/dualmonitors.sh* and chmod'd it:

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output DP-4 --primary
```

Created and edited */etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_my.conf*:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
allow-guest=false
display-setup-script=/usr/bin/dualmonitors.sh
session-setup-script=/usr/bin/dualmonitors.sh
```

Option 3) */etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf* file doesn't exist by default for some reason, only */etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/* directory exists, made the *lightdm.conf* file anyways and edited it with the same contents as 01_my.conf:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
allow-guest=false
display-setup-script=/usr/bin/dualmonitors.sh
session-setup-script=/usr/bin/dualmonitors.sh
```

**Results:** Nothing works. Login window appears on left-most (first) monitor on startup, and then appears on right-most (third) monitor after logging out, never once appearing on the middle (second) monitor which is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I have two monitors, and the left one is primary. UEFI, grub, and my login session all recognize that correctly, but the LightDM login screen has it backward.

I used option 1 with a value of zero, and that fixed it for me:

```
[greeter]
active-monitor=0
```