# Xubuntu Studio - login prompt opens on wrong screen on dual-monitor setup

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xfce, lightdm

This PC is Ubuntu Studio with Xfce, used as a gaming emulator and home cinema.

Primary display: Dell 2009W (1680x1050) - monitor
Secondary display: Panasonic PTAT6000 (1920x1080) - projector
GPU: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB
Driver: nvidia-driver-510
Display manager: lightdm

I have several display-related problems to do with different games and emulators messing up the screen resolution, the defaults not being remembered, and the options I need on the NVIDIA control panel going off the sides of the screen at very low resolutions.

But this question is about when the PC is switched on and the login prompt pops up for Xfce. It's always on the projector, which is never on when the system boots - it's only switched on to watch a film.

How can I make the login prompt always appear on the Dell-2009W regardless of its logical display number?

I guess this might be a similar problem to:-

[Force gdm login screen to the primary monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11738/force-gdm-login-screen-to-the-primary-monitor)

but where it says gdm that's Gnome Display Manager so the steps for Xfce might be different.

Comment: Have you tried in display settings to change which monitor is primary? If you have tried some troubleshooting already please add what you have tried to the question with edit.

Comment: Which displaymanager are you using, `sddm` which comes with Ubuntustudio or `lightdm` which comes with `xubuntu-desktop`?

Comment: @mook765 - I seem to be using lightdm. I opened the file /etc/X11/default-display-manager as text and it had a single line: /usr/sbin/lightdm

Comment: @David the correct monitor is shown as the primary display in Applications>Settings>Display. The problem (seemingly) is that the login prompt isn't opening on it. But how can I tell if the system is using the same config files that this GUI edits?

Comment: @evild4ve Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1438167/edit) to add this very relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to mook765 highlighting lightdm, I've fixed this by opening

/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf

as text and adding

[greeter]

active-monitor=0

This was given by [Lightdm: Login window on wrong monitor every time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211926/lightdm-login-window-on-wrong-monitor-every-time)